# Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "release|any cpu" is invalid

Tags: azure-devops, node-modules, devops, azure-pipelines

I had setup the devops flow for one of my client application. It’s woking fine in build and release level. But after some days suddenly my build failed with the following error.

> node_modules\uws\build\binding.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "release|any cpu" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's the type of your project? Is it website app?

Comment: @Marina, Yes, it is an Angualr2 application.

Comment: What if you change to `**\*.publishproj` instead of `**\*.sln` in VS Build task?

Comment: currently I have 3 projects inside single solution, that's why I used the ***.sln instead of ***.proj

Comment: For website app, you should specify the .publishproj instead of .sln. If you also need to build other projects, just add additional tasks in order to build website app separately.

Comment: I have a lot of projects in my single solution, then I want to add multiple VS Build tasks. is there any alternative solutions for adding one or more VS Build tasks in to my current build definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162500/discussion-between-pradeep-and-marina-liu-msft).

Comment: The alternative ways are: option1: change the .sln before VS build task to remove the project info which you want to exclude build. option2: manage the website app in a separate solution.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, can you please elaborate option 1.

Comment: What's the VCS system do you use, Git or TFVC? Option1 can be much easier for Git VCS?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, I used the Git with VSTS

Comment: I added the detail steps for option 1, you can have a try.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, Thanks you helped a lot for me, but i did mistake in the VS Build Task i.e I used the **\*.sln in the VS build task instead using .sln (for example InnovationApp.sln).

Comment: Sure. For VS Build task, you should specify solution by `path/to/name.sln` or `**\*.sln`. I use `.sln` just stand for the solution file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **PowerShell tasks** to change the `.sln` file.

Assume if you want to build projects except a website project, then you can remove the website project info in `GlobalSection` of the .sln file.

Prerequisites:

Get the project ID you want to remove, the formate as `ECF93D95-5096-497E-B4B8-83416DABB516`.

Then add a PowerShell task **before** VS build task which build other projects. The script as:

```
git checkout $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCHNAME)
(get-content "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\relative\path\to\solution") -notmatch "{project_ID}.$(BuildConfiguration)" | out-file "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\relative\path\to\solution"
```

Such as below example to remove the project `ECF93D95-5096-497E-B4B8-83416DABB516` from `.sln` file:

```
git checkout $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCHNAME)
(get-content "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ConsoleAppCore\ConsoleAppCore.sln") -notmatch "{ECF93D95-5096-497E-B4B8-83416DABB516}.$(BuildConfiguration)" | out-file "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ConsoleAppCore\ConsoleAppCore.sln"
```

**After** the VS Build task, you can add another PowerShell task to recovery the changed `.sln`as the same version in git repo. The script as:

```
git reset --hard head
```

For building websit project except other projects, you can use the same way to skip the project for building.

**Note:** for PowerShell task, please **deselect** Fail on Standard Error option.

[image]

Comment: I tried with the above solution but i am getting the error like "[error]Switched to a new branch 'integration' Branch integration set up to track remote branch integration from origin.
[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script for Remove the Angular Project"

Comment: Sorry for the reminder and delay. You should deselect Fail on Standard Error option in Powershell task. And you can try again.

Comment: @pradeep Did you skip to build the project successful?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks @Marina, By seeing your updated answer I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use multiple solutions which target group of projects together (**Partitioned Solution**)
Here is link to get more info about it

[Partitioned Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668953.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Also I implement in many open source project, here one of them

[Project on GitHub using Partitioned Solution](https://github.com/DevOpsFounder/EC-GitHub/tree/dev/Technologies/DOTNET)
[image]

Comment: Currently I used two VS Build Tasks in my build definition, one for Angular2 application and other for entire solution file. But in the second VS Build task i am facing the same issue because in that Angular2 project is included. So, can you please tell me how to remove the angular2 project in the second VS build Task?

Comment: Create new solution which doesn't include the Angular2 project

Comment: It is an production application, so I can't do it separate right now. actually the same solution will work upto yesterday, but from yesterday on words facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once while using `VSTS`. I suggest you to use `MSBuild` arguments directly

Ho to add to `MSBuild` Arguments:

```
/p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) /p:Platform="$(BuildPlatform)"
```

Note: *leave Platform and Configuration empty*